Intellij no hace autocompletado al codigo de mi archivo .jsp
Estoy usando Intellij para la creación de Servlets.
El problema que tengo es que al intentar escribir código en mi archivo index.jsp (ya sea Html o Java), se me vuelve una tarea muy tediosa ya que el IDE reconoce mi archivo .jsp pero no me autocompleta el código.
Mi código es el siguiente:
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <%String hola = "Hola mundo con Java";%>
    <%=hola %>
    </body>
    </html>

Cabe aclarar que este codigo al ejecutar la app cumple su cometido, el cual es dar un h2 con hello world y mostrar el valor de la variable hola.
En todos los tutoriales simplemente al abrir el archivo ya se reconoce el código de forma correcta.

Hice la prueba de descargar el Intellij Ultimate Edition y casualmente, funciona todo correctamente...

Como puedes leer en su documentación, esta es una característica solamente soportada en la versión Ultimate
